# Loaded die two roll probability

Tags: probability

There is a loaded die for which the probability of rolling a 6 is 1/2. The probability for each other face appearing is 1/10. What is the probability of rolling a 4 and then a 6 on two tosses of the die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of two independent events $A$ and $B$ both occurring is $P(A \cap B)=P(A)*P(B)$

So in this case we get $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{20}$